# Drupal language negotiation

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a multi-language drupal setup (2 languages, english default). I want users to receive always content in the other language (lets say spanish) on initial page request, but keep english as default language for future language switch. So users will be redirected on initial load to site.com/es, but through the language switch will be able to go to site.com/ (which is english).

Any suggestions? Thank you.

(Apache, PHP)

Comment: can we do also something else for you? A Sandwich? A cold Cola? or a Beer? ;-)

Comment: almost funny. I asked for suggestions not code. but now that you offered, please a beer. double time :-)

Comment: Ok here is your cold Beer |__|)

Comment: May be you should save the spanish language in a cookie and if you want to redirect to the english site destroy the content of the coockie value not the cookie it self but just the value you have set like unset($_COOKIE['isspanish']);

Comment: it is not as trivial as it seems :-). go grab a beer and relax.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect users using preprocess in template.php file of your theme:

Approximate code:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the page templates.
 *
 * @param $vars
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("page" in this case.)
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  global $language;
  if ($language->language == 'en') { // Add here some checking for page, see print_r($vars)
    drupal_goto(url().'/es/'.$GET['q']); //goto es version
  }
}
```

Comment: well, i thought about it. the problem is that it has to run only once as the user loads the page initially. what will happen at a consecutive return to home?

Comment: now to run only once means that the state of the anonymous user has to be defined implicitly at beginning and end. beginning like you point out correctly is quite neatly taken care of with the aforementioned snippet, but end, mmm... none of the ajaxian-postmethod-php that come to my mind are worth sharing as they appear all elaborate hacks to me. funny things is the net nowadays.